# CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm new to iPhone programming and I'm working on socket programming,I'd like to know if there is any way to test if CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost() method worked. I'm more familiar with C socket programming in which all the methods used return an int value to test but this is void and there isn't any appropriate NSError from what I've read.

Comment: Take a look at [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) - a very good class to use as a listener or as a connecting socket. There are also samples (i think sample code is for mac only, not sure). If you don't like using ready made class then a good tutorial is here: [iPhone Network Programming](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43551)